# How to put terraform output into GITHUB_ENV

Tags: terraform, github-actions

I have the following terraform code:

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "eu-central-1"
}

terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket = "aws-project-terra"
    key    = "tf-state"
    region = "eu-central-1"
  }
}



module "ec2" {
  source = "./modules/ec2"

  ami           = "ami-0d1ddd83282187d18"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
}
```

which I run via github action:

```
name: Terraform-ansible-apply

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  Terraform:
    name: Terraform Plan & Apply
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Terraform Setup
        uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v1

      - name: Terraform Init
        run: terraform init
        working-directory: ./Terraform
        env:
          AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}

      - name: Terraform Validate
        run: terraform validate
        working-directory: ./Terraform

      - name: Terraform Apply
        id: tf-apply
        run: terraform apply -auto-approve
        working-directory: ./Terraform
        env:
          AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}

      - name: Save Terraform Outputs
        id: save-outputs
        run: |
          echo 'sg=$(terraform output -raw ec2_sg)' >> "$GITHUB_ENV"
        working-directory: ./Terraform

      - name: Use the value
        id: step_two
        run: |
          echo ${{ env.sg }}
```

the issue is that I don't get env.sg for environment variable in last step.
I get the error:

```
Run echo $(terraform output -raw ec2_sg) 
/home/runner/work/_temp/a9903635-fab4-4149-89fe-056eb08152ef/terraform-bin output -raw ec2_sg 
 Warning: No outputs found 
  
 The state file either has no outputs defined, or all the defined outputs 
 are empty. Please define an output in your configuration with the `output` 
 keyword and run `terraform refresh` for it to become available. If you are 
 using interpolation, please verify the interpolated value is not empty. You 
 can use the `terraform console` command to assist. 
 ::debug::Terraform exited with code 0. ::debug::stdout: 
 Warning: No outputs found
 
 The state file either has no outputs defined, or all the defined outputs
 are empty. Please define an output in your configuration with the `output`
 keyword and run `terraform refresh` for it to become available. If you are
 using interpolation, please verify the interpolated value is not empty. You
 can use the `terraform console` command to assist.
 ::debug::stderr: ::debug::exitcode: 0 ::set-output name=stdout::

 Warning: No outputs found
 
 The state file either has no outputs defined, or all the defined outputs
 are empty. Please define an output in your configuration with the `output`
 keyword and run `terraform refresh` for it to become available. If you are
 using interpolation, please verify the interpolated value is not empty. You
 can use the `terraform console` command to assist.
 ::set-output name=stderr:: ::set-output name=exitcode::0
```

I see the outputs in github workflow logs:

```
Outputs:

ec2_sg = "sg-015sdf8ad839881"
instance_ip = "3.75.232.345"
subnet_id = "subnet-05d345458f6c1a9"
```

as well I can print the output from command line:

```
terraform output -raw ec2_sg
sg-01599f8ad873c9881
```

So why I can't use this output via github environment variable?

Comment: Typo: use double quotes i.e. `echo "sg=$(terraform output -raw ec2_sg)" >> "$GITHUB_ENV"`. Single quotes make its enclosed content a string literal.

Comment: In my case, as you already have, I was missing the 'working-directory' in my output steps

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `terraform_wrapper` to **false** in the [setup-terraform](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/hashicorp-setup-terraform) action. There is an open issue https://github.com/hashicorp/setup-terraform/issues/20 to change this behavior.